# JQuery replace async:false with promise with classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, async-await, fetch

I have a custom template class/object, combining JQuery and plain JS.

```
function tplObject (url) {
  this.type = "tplObject";
  this.includePath = "tpl/";
  this.url;
  this.template;
  this.output;
  this.openTpl (url);
}
tplObject.prototype = {
  openTpl: function (url) {
    if (url.split(".").length == 1) url = url + '.tpl';
    this.url = url;
    $.ajax ({
      origin: this,
      type: "GET",
      url: this.includePath + url + '?' + window.config.cacheVersion,
      async: false,
      success: function (reply) {
        this.origin.template = reply;
        this.origin.output = reply;
      }
    });
  },
...lots of functions that manipulate this.output;
  getOutput: function () {
    this._clear();
    return this.output;
  },
```

I can manipulate the tpl objects, or fill one with the other, repeat fills, ect., like this:

```
var tpl1 = new tplObject ('tplFile');
tpl.changeVar ('from', 'to');
var tpl2 = new tplObject ('tplPart'); 
tpl1.fill (tpl2);
$('body').html(tpl1.getOutput());
```

I have been trying different approaches using promises and waits, but I cannot get the script to wait in the main stream until the openTpl function has responded.

I would love to use fetch(), as I also use a service worker. Than the response could be cached, so I wouldn't have to reload when I want to manipulate a new version of the template.

Any help will be very welcome!

Kind regard Ingrid

Comment: This is going to get complicated. You say "...lots of functions that manipulate this.output;", but `this.output` is derived asynchronously. Therefore many/all of the functions will need to be asynchronous, ie, they need to return a Promise, (which will probably need to resolve to `output`);

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I didn’t look at it that way yet, I have been trying to resolve before continuing. But indeed than needn’t be, I can resolve in getOutput, while the other data is loading, so I need a chain of Promises of all templates called and release final product is constructed. Food for thought, thanks. -Ingrid

Answer (score 0):

Making the whole function asynchonous would be alot of work. So in the mean time, I have made this old style declare-your-variables-first approach.

```
function fetchResources(processList) {
  return Promise.all(
    Object.keys(processList).map(function (i) {
      var obj = processList[i];
      return fetch(obj.fetchUrl)
      .then(r => r.text())
      .then(function (data) {
        obj.setData (data);
        return obj;
      })
      .catch(error => ({ error, obj }))
    })
  )
}
```

The setData is called on the original object.
To be applied like so.

```
fetchResources ([
  tpl1 = new tplObject ('tplFile'),
  tpl2 = new tplObject ('tplPart')
]).then (function () {
  tpl1.changeVar ('from', 'to');
  tpl1.fill (tpl2);
  $('body').html(tpl1.getOutput());
});
```

Comment: Ingrid, is this JavaScript? What is the `->` operator? Why have assignments in an array literal?

Comment: Anything constructed with `new` (or otherwise) should return an instance of the constructed object, not a Promise. 
After construction, you may call an asynchronous `.init()` method.

For example: 

 `let tpl1 = new tplObject('tplFile');
 let tpl2 = new tplObject('tplPart');
 Promise.all([tpl1.init(), tpl2.init()])
 .then(function() {
  tpl1.changeVar('from', 'to');
  tpl1.fill(tpl2);
  $('body').html(tpl1.getOutput());
 });`

Comment: so the -> was a mixup, I corrected it. The tpl1 and 2 are constructed objects. The function fetchResources, is the one returning the promise. fetchResources is passed the two just constructed objects, runs the funciton "setData" and then returns the objects.